# Checking for NULL inside inline function

Tags: c

Consider the following code:

```
static inline StatusCode SomeHelperFunction(SomeType* arg)
{
    return OtherFunction(&arg->member, "foo", "bar");
}

static StatusCode OtherFunction(SomeType2* param, const char* param2, const char* param3)
{
    if (param == NULL) /* return error status code */
    
    /* do some stuff and return OK status code */
}
```

The problem is that `OtherFunction` cannot take NULL (and it checks for it and returns correct instance of `StatusCode`. With given helper function I cannot ensure that `arg` is not null and dereferencing it would not crash the application. So null guard inside `SomeHelperFunction` seems reasonable. But it is inline function and if statement could break it. There are two options I think.

1. Do not check for null and just let the world burn
2. Do check and possibly break the inline benefits (what if I have 100 functions like that)

What do you do in this case?

Comment: I don't understand: what does inline have to do with the null check?

Comment: And what makes you think that an `if` statement in the helper function could break it, `inline` or not?

Comment: I think in specific cases strict compiler would not permit to have if statement inside inline function, thus removing inline from it (am I wrong)?

Comment: The compiler is not required to perform inlining optimization on the helper function regardless, but I see no particular reason to expect that whether it uses an `if` statement would be a significant factor in the compiler's decision.

Comment: You can also use a macro instead of an inlined function to force the "inlining" everywhere : #define SomeHelperFunction(arg) ((arg) ? OtherFunction(&(arg)->member, "foo", "bar") : return ERROR)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Put the conditional in the code and don't worry about it.

#### Compilers are powerful:

Consider the code:

```
static int SomeHelperFunction(int* arg) {
    return Foo(&arg, "foo", "bar");
}

static inline int SomeInlineHelperFunction(int* param) {
    if (param == NULL)
        return 3;
    return Foo(&param, "foo", "bar");
}

void entrypoint() {
    int x;
    SomeHelperFunction(&x);
    SomeInlineHelperFunction(&x);
}
```

clang will inline `SomeInlineHelperFunction` and `SomeHelperFunction`, and it will even optimize away the null check since it can determine that it is impossible to be false.

```
entrypoint():
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 16
        lea     rbx, [rsp + 12]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rbx
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     esi, offset .L.str
        mov     edx, offset .L.str.1
        call    Foo(int**, char const*, char const*)
        mov     qword ptr [rsp], rbx
        mov     rdi, rsp
        mov     esi, offset .L.str
        mov     edx, offset .L.str.1
        call    Foo(int**, char const*, char const*)
        add     rsp, 16
        pop     rbx
        ret
.L.str:
        .asciz  "foo"

.L.str.1:
        .asciz  "bar"
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zYfds8